# Android - How to upload an AUDIO file with Parse SDK

Tags: android, audio, file-upload, parse-platform, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to save some data and an audio file into my Parse Server database, here's the code I use:

```
audioURLString = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "_message.mp4";
```

The file gets stored into the Local root folder of my device, I can find it there so the file exists and it's actually a valid mp4 file, I can play it, now here's the code I use to save it on Parse:

```
ParseObject myObj = new ParseObject("Chats");

byte[] data = audioURLString.getBytes();
ParseFile audioFile = new ParseFile("message.mp4", data);
audioFile.saveInBackground();

myObj.put("message", audioFile);
```

Then if I check my Parse database I can find that **message.mp4** file and download it, but it's not a valid mp4 file at all, just 4Kb, I cannot play it with QuickTime nor in the app with MediaPlayer.

So I assume that my `byte[] data` conversion is wrong, does anybody know how to get bytes data out of that `audioURLString` (which is simply a `String`) and successfully upload the full file on Parse?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it out!**

Here's the code to convert my audio file into a byte Array:

```
// Save sound
byte[] soundBytes;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = 
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(audioURLString)));
    soundBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    soundBytes = toByteArray(inputStream);

    ParseFile audioFile = new ParseFile("message.mp4", soundBytes);
    myObj.put("message", audioFile);

} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: What is `toByteArray(inputStream);` ?

Comment: it's an array of bytes built from the input stream of a video

Comment: When copying and pasting your code into my activity, `toByteArray` is the only thing that's unresolved with red letters.

Comment: I assume it's a custom method, could you provide that method please?